# Convert array of records to JSON in Postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I'm having problems with converting an array of records into JSON with Postgresql.

**Version:** psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.3

Current query:

```
SELECT c.id, (select array(
        select (cp.id,cp.position)
        from contactposition cp
        where cp.contact_id_id = c.id  -- join on the two tables
        )
      ) as contactpositions
from contacts c;
```

Contact from table `contacts` can have many positions assigned from `contactposition` table.

Result is something like this:

```
| id (integer) | contactpositions (record[])                                          |
|--------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 5            | {"(21171326,\"Software Developer\")","(21171325,Contractor)" (...)"} |
```

But I would like it to be something like this:

```
| id (integer) | contactpositions (record[])                                          |
|--------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 5            | [{"id": 21171326, "position": "Software Developer", "id": 21171325, "position": "Contractor", (...)] |
```

I am aware of several helper functions like `array_to_json`, but I just can't get it to work.

I've tried:

```
SELECT c.id, array_to_json(select array(
            select (cp.id,cp.position)
            from contactposition cp
            where cp.contact_id_id = c.id
            )
          ) as contactpositions
from contacts c;
```

But it throws: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"`, so obviously I'm not using it right.

I would appreciate any tips, thanks!

Comment: Oops, updated it in the question. It is 9.5.3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_build_object()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) and [`jsonb_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select c.id, jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', cp.id, 'position', cp.position))
from contacts c
join contactposition cp on c.id = cp.contact_id
group by 1;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!